# Strongly typed form values in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

How can I bind the form and the underlying model types together?

Given

```ts
interface IUser {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
```

How do I generate:

```ts
form = new FormGroup<???>({
  name: new FormControl<string>(..)
  age: new FormControl<number>(...)
});
```

And retrieve the value:

```ts
const model = form.value // --> Expected to be IUser
```

In a strongly typed way, such that removing a field, or adding a new field would cause compilation issues, if the respective FormControl is missing / not of the correct type, and the compiler can guarantee that the form value comforms to the interface?

So `form.value as IUser` is not good enough, and neither is leaving off the type of the `

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so something like this seems to work, but I'm wondering if there is a more robust way to do this? I'd guess this would start having all sorts of problems with nested fields and arrays:

```
type FormControlsFor<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: FormControl<T[P]>
}

form = new FormGroup<FormControlsFor<IUser>>({
  name: new FormControl<string>(..)
  age: new FormControl<number>(...)
});

const model = form.value as Partial<IUser>;  // Any way to enforce this is not a partial?
```

Comment: You don't have to use generic, just this? 
type UserFormControls = {
  [key in keyof IUser]: FormControl;
};

Comment: That would make the FormControl non-strongly typed though, no?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an interface describing the form like this:

```
interface IUserForm {
    name: FormControl<string>,
    age: FormControl<number>
}
```

With this interface you can create the form group like this:

```
const form = new FormGroup<IUserForm>({
    name: new FormControl(),
    age: new FormControl(),
})
```

If you have a default values for your form you can skip the additional interface and create the form like this:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl<string>('', {nonNullable: true}),
    age: new FormControl<number>(0, {nonNullable: true}),
});
```

*keep in mind calling reset on the form in this case will reset it to the default values.*

Finally you can get the form value and assign it to your interface like this:

```
// this will not work
// const model: IUser = form.value;
const model: IUser = form.getRawValue();
```

*Note: `form.value` will always return Partial type as any of the controls in the form group could be disabled. Once control is disabled it is removed from the form value! Calling `gerRawValue` will return everything including disabled controls.*

Comment: This is exactly what I wish to avoid, since now I'd have two things describing the User, one with and one without `FormControl<>`. The intended question was how to avoid duplication.

Comment: the most important thing is to use getRawValue() method, instead of value property.